# Tkinter python: issue with clearing out the widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

Someone please help me figure this out.

I have the following problem in Tkinter Python. The problem is that the text is overlaying with the previous text. and/or is copying below that.

[image]

I've tried to use `label.config(root).pack()`  instead  of `Label(root, text="").pack()`
This kinda solves the problem it starts to write over the previous text but there are 2 problems with this.

1: the text old text/Entrys all still there, it just overlays.
2: this only works with `label.config`, and I would also like this to work with buttons and `Entrys(textbox)`

I've also tried `.pack_forget()` and `.destroy()` but unfortunately it did nothing.

---

### CODE

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import time
import os


def new_profile():
    global Var1, Var2
    var1 = StringVar()
    var2 = StringVar()

    Label(root, text="Create a new profile").pack()
    Label(root, text="User Name").pack()
    Entry(root, textvariable=var1).pack()

    Label(root, text="Password").pack()
    Entry(root, textvariable=var2).pack()

    Button(root, text="Create", command=create_profile).pack()
    Var1, Var2 = var1, var2
    return


def create_profile():

    text1 = Var1.get()
    text2 = Var2.get()
    print(text1)
    dict = {}
    dict['Name'] = text1
    dict['Password'] = text2


    pickle.dump(dict, open("test.txt", "wb"))


    dict1 = pickle.load(open("test.txt", "rb"))
    if dict1['Name'] == text1 and dict1['Password'] == text2:
        Label(root, text="").pack()
        Label(root, text="Profile creation successful", ).pack()
        Label(root, text="Name:" + " " + text1).pack()
        Label(root, text="Password:" + " " + text2).pack()

    else:
        Label(root, text="Something went wrong while creating your profile.", ).pack()
    return


def load_profile():
    select = "Load profile.."
    label.config(text=select)
    return



root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400+300+300")
root.title("client")


menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New Profile", command=new_profile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Load Profile", command=load_profile)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Profile Options", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)


label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you actually *need* to create new controls? If you kept references to the old ones, you could just update their `config` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

create a array such as

```
on_screen = []
```

at the start then name your widgets and and add them to the array

```
password_label = Label(root, text="Password").pack()
password = Entry(root, textvariable=var2).pack()
on_screen.append(password)
on_screen.append(password_label)
```

then use a for loop to destroy all the widgets in the array

```
for w in on_screen:
    w.destroy()
```